# Django; 2 model/class/tables pass into one template

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

Forgive me if I ask something foolish, I very new to coding industry

I been working on Django project to create dashboards to show case monitoring of an hydroponics greenhouse.

So I create two model;

```
class tank_system(models.Model):
PH = models.DecimalField(default=7.5,max_digits=3, decimal_places=1)
EC = models.DecimalField(default=13.3,max_digits=3, decimal_places=1)
Winlet = models.DecimalField(default=20.1, max_digits=3, decimal_places=1)
Woutlet = models.DecimalField(default=20.3,max_digits=3, decimal_places=1)
WaterLevel = models.IntegerField(default=500)
TempWater = models.IntegerField(default=25)
tanks = models.IntegerField(default=1)
datetime = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now())

class ambient (models.Model):
TempRoom = models.IntegerField(default=25)
CO2 = models.DecimalField(default=20.0, max_digits=3, decimal_places=1)
O2 = models.DecimalField(default=20.0,max_digits=3, decimal_places=1)
Humdity = models.IntegerField(default=25)
Room = models.IntegerField(default=1)
datetime = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now())
```

and I render the data of two model into one single template

here my views;

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from CGI.models import tank_system, ambient

def index(request):
    tank = tank_system.objects.all()
    room = ambient.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'CGI/Pages/DashBoard.html', {'tank': tank},{'room': room})
```

when I try this I only got data form 1 table

Here my html template;

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
 {% block content %}
{%load staticfiles%}
 {% load static %}
 <div class = "containor">
 <div class ="row" id = "row1">
 <div class ="col-sm-6" style="background-color:">
    <h2>Camera</h2>
 </div>

<div class ="col-sm-6" style="background-color:">
    <h2>Ambinet</h2>
</div>
</div>

<div class = "containor">
    <div class="row" id="row2">
        <div class ="col-sm-6" id="Cam1" style="background-color:">
            <div class="containor">
                <video id="livestream" width="550" height="350" autoplay></video>
                 <canvas class = "my-4 chartjs-render-monitor" id="live_vid" height="1"></canvas>
                <script src="{% static 'FrounterWeb/JS-code/Stream.JS' %}" ></script>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class ="col-sm-2" id="Humdity" style="background-color:">
            <div class="containor">
                <center>
                    <picture>
                        <img src="{% static 'FrounterWeb/img/Humidty_icon.png' %}" alt="RoomTemp">
                    </picture>
                <br>
                    <h1>
                    {% for ambient in room %}
                         {% if forloop.first %}
                         {{  ambient.Humdity }}
                         {% endif %}
                         {% endfor %}
                    %</h1>
                </center>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class ="col-sm-2" id="Roomtemp" style="background-color:">
            <div class="containor">
                <center>
                    <picture>
                        <img src="{% static 'FrounterWeb/img/RoomTemp.png' %}" alt="RoomTemp">
                    </picture>
                <br>
                    <h1>
                    {% for ambient in room %}
                         {% if forloop.first %}
                         {{  ambient.TempRoom }}
                         {% endif %}
                         {% endfor %}
                    C</h1>
                </center>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class ="col-sm-2" id="co2" style="background-color:">
            <div class="containor">
                <center>
                    <picture>
                        <img src="{% static 'FrounterWeb/img/co2_icon.png' %}" alt="co2">
                    </picture>
                <br>
                    <h1>
                    {% for ambient in room %}
                         {% if forloop.first %}
                         {{  ambient.CO2 }}
                         {% endif %}
                         {% endfor %}
                    </h1>
                </center>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>

<div class = "containor" >
    <div class="row" id = "row3" >
        <div class ="col" style="background-color:">
            <center>
                <h2>Water tank</h2>
            </center>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class = "containor">
    <div class="row" id ="row4" >

        <div class ="col-sm-2">
            <div class="containor">
                <center>
                        <picture>
                            <img src="{% static 'FrounterWeb/img/pHicon.png' %}" alt="co2">
                        </picture>
                    <br>
                    <h1>
                    {% for tank_system in tank %}
                         {% if forloop.first %}
                         {{ tank_system.PH }}
                         {% endif %}
                         {% endfor %}
                    </h1>
                </center>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class ="col-sm-2">
            <div class="containor">
                <center>
                        <picture>
                            <img src="{% static 'FrounterWeb/img/EC-icon.png' %}" alt="co2">
                        </picture>
                    <br>
                    <h1>
                    {% for tank_system in tank %}
                         {% if forloop.first %}
                         {{ tank_system.EC }}
                         {% endif %}
                         {% endfor %}
                    %</h1>
                </center>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class ="col-sm-2">
            <div class="containor">
                <center>
                        <picture>
                            <img src="{% static 'FrounterWeb/img/WaterTemp.png' %}" alt="co2">
                        </picture>
                    <br>
                    <h1>
                    {% for tank_system in tank %}
                         {% if forloop.first %}
                         {{ tank_system.TempWater }}
                         {% endif %}
                         {% endfor %}
                    C</h1>
                </center>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class ="col-sm-2">
            <div class="containor">
                <center>
                        <picture>
                            <img src="{% static 'FrounterWeb/img/Flow-icon.png' %}" alt="co2">
                        </picture>
                    <br>
                    <h1>
                    {% for tank_system in tank %}
                         {% if forloop.first %}
                         {{ tank_system.Winlet }}
                         {% endif %}
                         {% endfor %}
                    ml/hr</h1>
                </center>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class ="col-sm-2">
            <div class="containor">
                <center>
                        <picture>
                            <img src="{% static 'FrounterWeb/img/Flow-out-icon.png' %}" alt="co2">
                        </picture>
                    <br>
                    <h1>
                    {% for tank_system in tank %}
                         {% if forloop.first %}
                         {{ tank_system.Woutlet }}
                         {% endif %}
                         {% endfor %}
                    ml/hr</h1>
                </center>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class ="col-sm-2">
            <div class="containor">
                <center>
                        <picture>
                            <img src="{% static 'FrounterWeb/img/waterlevel-icon.png' %}" alt="Waterlevel">
                        </picture>
                    <br>
                    <h1>
                    {% for tank_system in tank %}
                         {% if forloop.first %}
                         {{ tank_system.tanks }}
                         {% endif %}
                         {% endfor %}
                    L</h1>
                </center>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>

<div class = "containor">
    <div class="row" id="row5" >

        <div class ="col-sm-6" >
            <h1>Water data</h1>
        </div>

        <div class ="col-sm-6" >
            <h1>Room data</h1>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>

<div class = "containor">
    <div class="row" id="row6" >

        <div class ="col-sm-6" >
            <div class="float-sm-none" id = Waterchart>

            </div>
        </div>

        <div class ="col-sm-6" >
            <div class="float-sm-none" id = Roomchart>


            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

here picture better understanding; 
[image: picture better understanding]

If you could help I, really appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have 4 arguments in your render of which 2 is context. It needs only **one** dictionary with context or you can make a context dictionary variable and pass it as argument in render.

Try this:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from CGI.models import tank_system, ambient

def index(request):
    tank = tank_system.objects.all()
    room = ambient.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'CGI/Pages/DashBoard.html', {'tank': tank,'room': room})
```

**OR**

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from CGI.models import tank_system, ambient

def index(request):
    tank = tank_system.objects.all()
    room = ambient.objects.all()
    context = {
           'tank': tank,
           'room': room  
       }
    return render(request, 'CGI/Pages/DashBoard.html',context)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can pass data using two different ways

```
def index(request):
    tank = tank_system.objects.all()
    room = ambient.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'CGI/Pages/DashBoard.html', {'tank': tank,'room': room}) 
                  or 
    return render(request, 'CGI/Pages/DashBoard.html', locals())
locals() stands for get all local variable/objects and pass to the html as context
```

Comment: Please don’t use `locals()` in your code for doing this. It’s really bad programming style, making it hard to maintain.

Comment: I agree with you @dirkgroten. but for small functions it seems to be ok. 
I got your point on locals(). it will collect all the data and sends to html, but here there are some data which is not necessary to send to html. that time instead of locals() we can use context.

Answer (score 1):

In your index method, make changes as:

```
def index(request):
    tank = tank_system.objects.all()
    room = ambient.objects.all() 
    return render(request, 'CGI/Pages/DashBoard.html', {'tank': tank, 'room': room})
```